# What's the state of the art on stochastic representations of hyperbolic PDE?

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I saw this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2382

Chatterjee gives a representation of many solutions of the wave equation in terms of Brownian motion. I haven't seen much other than this. Is there any recent developments?

Comment: I am not sure about the state of the art, but there is a nice paper of Pal-Shkolnikov which shows hows hyperbolic PDE arise from intertwining relations between diffusion processes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0857

Comment: Is Navier-Stokes considered Hyperbolic ? If yes, then see this:Constantin, Peter, and Gautam Iyer. "A stochastic Lagrangian representation of the three‐dimensional incompressible Navier‐Stokes equations." CPAM (2008)